# HTML5 video source does not understand filestorage path

Tags: java, html, tomcat, video, file-storage

HTML5 video source does not understand file storage path.
For example filepath is d:/filestorage or c:\tomcat\temp

```
 <video width="620" height="580" controls="true">
                                    <source  src="#{showVideoBean.fileModel.filepath}" type="video/mp4 .mp4"/>
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video>
```

As I understand source understand only path as URL, like http://

How to orgonize video files file storage and play it with HTML5 video tag.
I do not want store file under project folders.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:
I created simple web application in \webapps\file-storage
it is included WEB-INF and web.xml
In my backend I am storing video files in \webapps\file-storage
And in the web page

```
 <video width="620" height="580" controls="true">
                                    <source  src="/file-storage/#{showVideoBean.fileModel.filepath}" type="video/mp4 .mp4"/>
                                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                                </video> 

#{showVideoBean.fileModel.filepath} equals /some/folders/filename.mp4
```